# Doctrine DQL com WHERE não funciona

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-2

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta numa tabela de usuarios que tem FK de 4 outras tabelas, mas creio que não vem ao caso, e realizo 2 filtros no WHERE, por exemplo `WHERE login = 'string' AND id <> numero;`. Porém não retorna nada, **obs.:** coloco as informações exatas para trazer um registro da tabela.

Por curiosidade testei sem essas condições, sem o WHERE, e traz os todos os registros da tabela. Então acho que possa ser erro de sintaxe, será? Estou fazendo como está no exemplo da documentação: **http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html**.

Segue o código no pastebin: **http://pastebin.com/xXpctT4v**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei o erro. Em:

```
//** UsuariosDAO.php extends DAO.php **//
public function queryChkLogin(\Projeto\Core\Model\Usuarios $usuario)
```

Troquei:

```
return $this->queryDAO($dql);
```

por

```
return $this->queryDAO($dql, $param);
```

Tirei o **`$param`** para testar somente o script com as variáveis direto nele, acabei esquecendo de adicionar ele depois... Dá uma raiva quando é besteira dessas viu! hehehe